# How to import project Laravel to other Laravel project

Tags: php, maven, laravel, import, composer-php

- When I worked with Spring MVC in Java , it manage all dependency by Maven and I think with Laravel , all library are managed by Composer. (I'm not sure, cause I'm a newbie in Laravel ^^ )
- Now, I have 2 laravel project, one **common project** and one **sub project** , in sub project how can I use common project through Composer management ?

Comment: what do you mean for sub project?.  all project dependencies are managed by composer automatically and you'll see then in your conposer.json file, and installed by default in vendor folder. Dont understant your cuestion at all but if you mean to build your custom library, I recommend to check this documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages, then use github and packagist to make them available online.

Comment: so we can't use my custom library on my local ( not push code to git server ) ?

Comment: You can point composer at a local repo. It was an update made pretty recently: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Pitchinnate, you can include a local repository via Composer. 
You'll want to reference the second repository that the first is dependant upon in the "repositories" section of your composer.json, and then require it.

Ex:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "*@dev"
    }
}
```

This should allow you to link your project and sub-project, if we've understood your question correctly.

Cheers!